# How to prevent Rollup from moving export statements to the top?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, node-modules, commonjs, rollup

I am a library developer and recently ran into a problem with Rollup: it skips side-effect statements of the entry files, moves the bottom export statement to the top, and generates incorrect bundles.

Here is a small repository to reproduce all the things, include the rollup result: https://github.com/xyzingh/rollup-move-export .

[image: directory structure]

There is an additional module `moduleA` that will be imported in the entry `entry.dev.js` and will not be referenced at all in the entry `entry.prod.js`.

**src/entry.dev.js**

```js
import { moduleA } from "./moduleA/api";
import { registerModule } from "./core/register";

registerModule(moduleA); // side-effect statement

export * from "./core/index"; // rollup actually moves this statement to line 3 and then makes bundle
```

**src/entry.prod.js**

```js
import { registerModule } from "./core/register";

registerModule(null); // side-effect statement

export * from "./core/index";  // rollup moves this statement to line 2
```

**src/moduleA/api.js**

```js
export const moduleA = {
    // ...
};
```

**src/core/register.js**

```js
// I don't need to import anything, but anything under
// this folder (src/core/**) should import me.

let depModule = undefined;

export function registerModule(m) {
  depModule = m;
}

export function getModule() {
  return depModule;
}
```

**src/core/index.js**

```js
import { getModule } from "./register";

console.log(getModule()); // ⚠ incorrectly print "undefined"

export const abc = 123;
```

simple `rollup.config.js`:

```js
export default [
  {
    input: "./src/entry.dev.js",
    output: {
      file: "./dist/lib.dev.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
  },
  {
    input: "./src/entry.prod.js",
    output: {
      file: "./dist/lib.prod.js",
      format: "cjs",
    },
  },
];
```

Result (dev entry)

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

const moduleA = {
  id: "A",
};

// I don't need to import anything, but anything under
// this folder (src/core/**) should import me.

let depModule = undefined;

function registerModule(m) {
  depModule = m;
}

function getModule() {
  return depModule;
}

console.log(getModule()); // ⚠ incorrectly print "undefined"

const abc = 123;

registerModule(moduleA); // side-effect statement

exports.abc = abc;
```

Comment: Moving `export` declarations around, or moving `import` declarations without changing their order, does not change semantics. Your code simply doesn't work in ES6 semantics, it's not the fault of the bundler.

Comment: @Bergi Uh, if replace `import` and `export` with CJS syntax `require` and `exports`, it can work. So how to let rollup make bundle in the semantics of CJS?

Comment: Yes, `require` works differently than `import`. No, you should not write code with ES6 syntax but CJS semantics, and I doubt rollup supports that.